# Ruby conditions

Tags: ruby

I want to take any truthy value from two expressions, for example `2`, or take nothing. It can be done as:

```
if exp1
  a = exp1
elsif exp2
  a = exp2
end
```

I tried to make it short, and have the following:

```
a = 1 if exp1|| 2 if exp2
```

However ruby returns `1` in this case. What is the correct syntax in ruby to do this?

Comment: You mean you have one condition and you assign value to `a` according to it?

Comment: you can try a= 1: false ? 2  something like this

Comment: No I have it as I wrote it - 2 'ifs' in the same line , it might be that it can't be done like that ?

Comment: Why not just try that and see if it throws an error?

Comment: No I need a to take either truthy value from them , or else a to be null and take nothing

Comment: @Joel_Blum are both examples supposed to be equivalent? Where do `1` and `2` come from?

Answer (score 8):

This should work:

```
a = exp1 || exp2 || a
```

Comment: This checks the validity of `a` at first not `exp1`. It's nothing equivalent to `if exp1
  a = exp1
elsif exp2
  a = exp2
end`

Comment: @konsolebox you're right, didn't see that.

Comment: @konsolebox I've updated my answer, I hope I got it right this time :-)

Comment: Yes. It's simpler than mine. +1

Answer (score 1):

```
a = exp1 ? exp1 : exp2 ? exp2 : a
```

Equivalent to:

```
if exp1,
    a is set to exp1
else if exp2,
    a is set to exp2
else
    a is set to a, which is virtually equivalent to doing nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax:

```
a = (1 if false) || (2 if true)
```

Comment: I accepted it by mistake... it's not what I needed . I want my variable to keep it's original value if both conditions are falsy but that doesn't happen here.the only way that I can see is the long way I wrote in my question.

Answer (score 0):

```
if exp1
  a = exp1
elsif exp2
  a = exp2
end
```

Can be shortened to

```
a = if exp1
  exp1
elsif exp2
  exp2
end
```

Or, if you prefer one-liners:

```
a = if exp1 then exp1 elsif exp2 then exp2 end
```

Any attempt to shorten it even further will change the semantics. For example:

```
a = exp1 || exp2 || nil
```

will evaluate `exp1` exactly once and `exp2` at most once, whereas the original snippet will evaluate `exp1` once or twice and `exp2` either twice or never.

(To be fair: my example will also change the meaning IFF `a` appears in `exp1`. In the OP's original code, an occurrence of `a` in `exp1` will be interpreted as a method call, in my example as a local variable dereference which will evaluate to `nil`.)